# Angle Between Two Faces of a Triangular Pyramid

Tags: geometry

A regular triangular pyramid has all of edges of length 36. What is the angle between any two faces of this pyramid?

I have no idea what to do for this problem. Can someone explain to me what an angle between two faces is?

Comment: Why do edge lengths have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: idk thats what the problem said

Comment: Any regular tetrahedron will have the same dihedral angle (angle between two faces), regardless of edge length.

Answer (score 1):

The lengths of the sides of the regular tetrahedron are irrelevant.

Hint:  Find the vectors from the tetrahedron's center to the center of two faces.  Then calculate the angle between them.

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate on that

Comment: Could you show what work you've done?  Where you've gotten stuck?  What isn't clear about my posting?  What *specifically* you don't understand?

Comment: i dont know how to "find the vectors"

Comment: **Vector**:  A line from the tetrahedron center (average of four vertices) to a face center (average of three vertices).

Comment: Further hint: a regular tetrahedron is vertex inscribable into a cube. Thus the face vectors of the tetrahedron just point to the omitted vertices of that cube.

Answer (score 0):

Let the regular tetrahedron be ABCD with ABC as the base, D as the highest vertex, ADB and and CDB as its slant faces.

[image]

From ABD (which is an equilateral triangle), we need to find the altitude AX.

Similarly, find CX from CBD. Note that since the tetrahedron is regular, the above mentioned two altitudes will (1) meet at the same point X; and (2) have the same length.

The required angle can be found by applying cosine law to the triangle AXC.

Answer (score -2):

This is asking for the angle defect between the two faces. To find the angle defect or the answer to your question, do 360 degrees minus the sum of the interior angles meeting at the vertex of where the two faces meet. The answer of that will be the answer to your question.